# Error: No error handlers are registered, logging exception

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Have created a bot which will run every Friday to retrieve FOMC Fed-Rate data.

However, the terminal occur below error :

**"No error handlers are registered, logging exception."**

Here's my code:

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import Updater
import telegram
import datetime, pytz
import ws_bot_web_scraping

def print_CME_targetFedRate(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):

    ws_bot_web_scraping.print_CME_targetFedRate(context)

#Server Start
#===========================================================
def server_start(update: telegram.Update, context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):

    print("Telegram_bot_misc Started.")
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,text=':)')
    context.job_queue.run_daily(print_CME_targetFedRate,datetime.time(hour=17, minute=33, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')),days=(4,),context=update.message.chat_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    u = Updater('<myToken>', use_context=True)
    j = u.job_queue

    dispatcher = u.dispatcher

    j.set_dispatcher(dispatcher)
    timer_handler = CommandHandler('s', server_start)
    u.dispatcher.add_handler(timer_handler)
    u.start_polling()
    j.start()
    u.idle()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception just tells you that within the `ws_bot_web_scraping.print_CME_targetFedRate(context)` call, the line `context.bot.sendMediaGroup(chat_id=context.job.context,media=media)` failed. The error message reported by Telegram is just "Group send failed".

Why exactly the media group could not be send is not clear from the error message, but it's also not clear from your question since you e.g. didn't include the code for `ws_bot_web_scraping.print_CME_targetFedRate`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`